# Is there a way to raise PropertyChanged when binding to Model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In our WPF/MVVM application, we are binding to property of the `Model` directly because the `Model` is from legacy library (we added the support of `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `Model` class). I.e., the code of `ViewModel` looks like

```
Public Class MyViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Public Property Model As MyModel

End Class
```

And then the binding looks like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Prop1}" />
```

Everyting worked fine until I have this requirement to have some properties in the `ViewModel` which depend on `Model.Prop1`. Specifically, I am binding the `ItemSource` of one `ComboBox` to a property of collection in the `ViewModel`, and this collection should be refreshed/recalculated whenever `Model.Prop1` is changed. The code looks like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

I have some options but they are not good in my opinion:

1. I can have `Model` class hold a reference of `ViewModel`. And in the setter of Prop1 in the `Model` I update the MyColleciton property of `ViewModel`. Of course it is not a good idea
2. Use `EventAggregator` for the communication between `Model` and `ViewModel`. Not efficient in my opinion plus I need to make big change in the `Model` class too.
3. Let `ViewModel` have one property `Prop1` and bind to this. In the getter of it return Model.Prop1 and in the setter assign `ModelProp1 = Value`. This is my current solution but there is one problem: in our `Model` we have other property/attribute which are useful and we create a common `Style` based on this property/attribute. For example, when the Model.Prop1 is changed, another property called `IsDirty` in `Model` class is set to `True` and in the `View` we change the color. But if we use Prop1 from `ViewModel`, instead of from `Model`, we lose this common `Style` behavior like other properties.

So now I still want to use the binding to `{Binding Model.Prop1}` (not create a wrapper property in the `ViewModel`) but somehow notify other properties in the `Model` when it is changed. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that *we added the support of `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the Model class*. Now if that means that you extended, or added to the original class and added calls to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event from each property, then you can easily find out which property was changed using that event:

```
Model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
```

Then in the `PropertyChanged` handler:

```
private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Prop1") 
    {
        // The Prop1 property value has changed
        RefreshYourCollection();
    }
}
```

However, if by *we added the support of `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the Model class*, you mean that your view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, then in reality, you have *not* added the support of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to your `Model` class and you cannot do this.

If that is the case, then you will first need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly for each relevant property in the class. If you cannot change the original class, then you should extend it in a class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly and expose each property of the original class as new properties that notify the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean the first case: the `Model` class itself implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I see you point and I will  try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't like having the `Navigation Property` like `Model.Prop1` because you end up with simple problems like this.

What you have to do is create a `ViewModel` that you only need to show in the `UI` and wrap the properties of the `Model` from there.

1. I don't like this idea. Keep in mind that `Model` here doesn't mean it's the actual entity from the `Database`. In my opinion, `ViewModel` has a reference to the `Model` that it have properties that needs to be displayed in the `UI`.
2. You don't even need aggregator or a messaging service just to update it. The refresh issue should be handled in the `ViewModel` not in the `Model` and I strongly disagree that `model` should listen to events
3. I'd go to this but then like I said in the beginning, just wrap what you need in the `UI` including other properties that are useful i.e., when `Model.Prop1` is changed then in the setter of the `ViewModel.Prop1` it updates the `IsDirty` in the `Model`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I need to display ALL properties from the `Model`, which has about 20-30 properties. So to go with 3) I need 20-30 wrapper properties in `ViewModel` which is somehow redundant in my opinion(what's the point of having M-V-VM, instead of M-VM, if I am not supposed to use `Model.Prop1` and need to create wrapper properties in VM for every property of the `Model`).

Comment: But to be fair not all properties in my `Model` should trigger the update of some (collection) properties in the `ViewModel`. So I guess I can use your suggestion in 3) for those which do trigger the update. For others that don't, I can still simply keep the binding like `Binding Model.Prop1` and not expose the wrapper properties in VM

Comment: @tete The point is that you don't clutter you `Model` with other `Business logic` for a certain view. If you want to have a custom logic for a different view then you'll have a `Model` properties that were suppose for `ViewA` but then `ViewB` now has it. Now imagine when the `ViewA` has to change and then `ViewB` also has to change. From 50 lines of code for the `Model` now turns into `100`. Imagine the mess you have to change instead of having a `ViewModel`. It's like saying why follow `MVVM` if I can just do straight behind the code and get what I need since it is redundant

Comment: That makes sense. I was asking because I did see some project which only had `View` and `ViewModel`. But that application was built from scratch (so no legacy class as `Model`) and there was simple one-View to one-ViewModel relation.

Comment: @tete I'd say think of `Model` as your `Business object` not the `Entity` from your `Database` that can be reused between `ViewModels`. :)

Comment: Yes, especially many of our `Model` classes are from legacy software which dated back from 90s (we ported from VBA into VB.NET 10 years ago)

Comment: I think I'd prefer @Sheridan answer. It's really just doing the same thing from two angles: 1) create wrapper prop and bind in `ViewModel` and in the setter notify the `Model` or 2) bind to `Model` prop using nested binding while add event handler between the `ViewModel` and `Model`. But I have two reasons why I choose 2). Firstly it still feels unnecessary (so far) to create the SAME wrapper from `Model` in the `ViewModel`. I agree with you in the situation when we need two `ViewModel` for the same `Model` (business object). But in my opinion the difference in mainly in the "View" part of

Comment: the VM (prop mainly for the UI). For example, I am exposing the a property of type `IEnumerable` in the VM for the `View`'s `ComboBox` to bind its ItemSource to. But this is just minor. The more important reason is, our additional UI apperance (the IsDirty indication I want to keep in line with other property), directly depend on the binding property itself. `Binding Model.Prop1` makes the `TextBox` indicate different colors if Model.Prop1 is dirty. Our `Model` already support such IsDirty function. But if I use the wrapper property I need to add the same function for the `ViewModel`